# Creating weighted matrix with lettered edges

Tags: java

Is it at all possible to create an adjacency matrix that displays letters as the edges instead of numbers. For example, a weighted graph.

```
. a b c d e f  
a 0 1 0 0 0 0  
b 0 0 0 4 0 0  
c 0 0 1 0 0 0  
d 0 0 0 3 0 0  
e 0 2 0 0 0 0  
f 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've tried everything as far as testing out my theories in accomplishing such task, such as

```
int let = 0;
String str = "a b c d e f";
char[] list = new char[str.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    list[i] = str.charAt(i);
}
//To create the char array with letters used for the matrix
System.out.println();
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%-3d", list[i]);
}
System.out.println();
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%-3d", list[i]);
    for(int x = 0; x < list.length; x++)
    {
          System.out.printf("%-3d", let);
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

I just get a bunch of errors about printformat, and converting, and such. (Don't have eclipse open at the moment)

It works phenomenal if I replace (list[i]) with (i+1) to get numbers 1-6, but just nothing for letters.
Is it even possible to accomplish this task? How would one go about creating a weighted matrix with letter edges if it's not possible.

This question may not be challenging for the majority of you, but as a beginner java programmer, I'm curious to learn, even if I have to suffer humility. No other way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print letters by casting the int values to `char`and adding the appropriate offset for the ASCII character you want. This example will print the letters a-f.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-3c", (char) (i+97));
}
```

The ASCII value for 'a' is 97, 'b' is 98 and so on.

For reference: an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: I didn't realize format "%-3c" was for letters and "%-3d" was (double)? I'm not sure. That was well over my head on that. Thanks so much boss!

Comment: @jeffreyzachary `%d`is actually for `signed decimal integer`. `%f`is for floating point numbers :)

Comment: Thank you for that! I just recently started experimenting printf(); it is definitely useful!